# Including External Library in Android project

Tags: android

I am new to android I thought of using this [Opensource library](https://code.google.com/p/devmil-android-color-picker/)   but I don't know how to download it and **include it in my project** since there is not **.jar file**.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html. check this refer the library project in your android project.

Answer (score 2):

Set the library up as an Android library:

1. Right-click on the library project
2. Select Properties
3. Go to the Android tab
4. Mark the project as the library

Then set your application to use the library:

1. Right-click on the library project
2. Select Properties
3. Go to the Android tab
4. Add a library at the bottom

That way, you will now be using the library when working on your app.